# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x (\ln(x))^2}{x^4 + x^2 + 1}\text{ d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

What is the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x (\ln(x))^2}{x^4 + x^2 + 1}\text{ d}x$?

#### This is a question I came up with myself. It is not homework.

I constructed this example to make the following technique work:

> Integrate $\frac{z (\log(z))^3}{z^4 + z^2 + 1}$ along a "key-hole" contour. The argument can be made rigorous by splitting the contour into two parts, and using two different branch cuts for each part. **Warning:** This method is time-consuming and not for the faint-hearted

Comment: To the down-voter: It's a valid question, and I've certainly tried it myself! Please read the tooltip first before clicking: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Which part of the calculation you got stuck at?

Comment: @nchar Did I not say "I constructed it" myself? Of course I didn't get stuck. It was just tedious. However, I think it is useful to know that the technique works!

Comment: What's your question then? Please be explicit.

Comment: @nchar I'm just sharing the question I came up with. What is wrong with that!?

Comment: Ok I see. I thought you need help with computing the integral.

Comment: What's with all the down-votes? I might just delete this, since it appears that people do not appreciate this kind of contribution.

Comment: The integral would be more interesting without the factor $x$ in front. The factor $x$ makes the evaluation easy because you can just substitute $x^2 = u$.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: how on earth is this question a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @Bombyxmori: No, not even close.  One has branch point singularities at the poles and is a tough problem, the other is more straightforward.  Have you even looked at the solutions?  Tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: The point is, it's not a duplicate.  Either you don't understand the art, or you don't understand what a duplicate is.  Either way, not a duplicate.  End of story.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{x\ln^2{x}}{x^4+x^2+1}dx
&=\frac{1}{8}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln^2{x}}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\frac{(1-x)\ln^2{x}}{1-x^3}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\int^1_0\left(x^{3n}-x^{3n+1}\right)\ln^2{x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{(3n+1)^3}-\frac{1}{(3n+2)^3}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1/3}\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(3z+1)^3}\\
&=-\frac{1}{108}\left(2\pi^3\cot(\pi z)\csc^2(\pi z)\right)\Bigg{|}_{z=-1/3}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^3}{81\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is a truly tour-de-fource!

Answer (score 4):

Let's actually do the integral using the keyhole contour.  It may be time-consuming but it is not as bad as it looks.

We can begin by simplifying the integral using the substitution $u=x^2$:

$$I = \frac18 \int_0^{\infty} du \frac{\log^2{u}}{u^2+u+1} $$

Consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^3{z}}{z^2+z+1}$$

where $C$ is the keyhole contour, as pictured below.

[image]

The integral over the circular arcs vanish, and the contour integral is equal to

$$i \left ( -6 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+x+1} + 8 \pi^3  \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\right ) + 12 \pi^2  \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+x+1}$$

We can easily show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+x+1} = 0$$

by splitting up the integration interval into $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ and subbing $x=1/u$ in the latter subinterval.

Now, we can evaluate the other integral any way we want, but let's stay consistent within our chosen methodology, and evaluate the integral using the residue theorem, all the same.  Let the poles of the denominator be $z_{\pm}$; here

$$z_+ = e^{i 2 \pi/3} \quad z_-=e^{i 4 \pi/3} $$

Then

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} = - \left (\frac{\log{z_+}}{2 z_++1} +\frac{\log{z_-}}{2 z_-+1}\right ) = -\frac{i 2 \pi/3}{i \sqrt{3}} +  \frac{i 4 \pi/3}{i \sqrt{3}} = \frac{2 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

The contour integral is of course equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at $z=z_{\pm}$. Thus we have

$$-3 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+x+1} + 4 \pi^2 \frac{2 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}} = \left (\frac{\log^3{z_+}}{2 z_++1} +\frac{\log^3{z_-}}{2 z_-+1}\right ) = \frac{56 \pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}}$$

Thus, from above, we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x \log^2{x}}{x^4+x^2+1} = \frac{2 \pi^3}{81 \sqrt{3}} $$

Comment: @Bombyxmori: By using the $\log^3{z}$ over the keyhole contour, we are able to recover the integral over $\log^2{x}$ because, about the branch point, the contour integral is equal to $$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^3{x}-(\log{x}+i 2 \pi)^3}{x^2+x+1} $$ and the $\log^3{x}$ terms cancel. This is true for general powers of log.

Comment: I see. This is obviously the crucial step I was missing. Now the set up is clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x\
+\ \overbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\dsc{x}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{1 \over x}}}
\\[5mm]&=2\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\dsc{x}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{x^{1/2}}}}\ =\
={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^2 + x + 1}\,\dd x
=\ \overbrace{{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x^{3}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\dsc{x}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{x^{1/3}}}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x^{1/3}}\ln^{2}\pars{x^{1/3}} \over 1 - x}\,
{1 \over 3}\,x^{-2/3}\,\dd x
={1 \over 108}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{x^{-2/3} - x^{-1/3}}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,
\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 108}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\ \partiald[2]{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu - 2/3} - x^{\mu - 1/3} \over 1 - x}\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 108}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\ \partiald[2]{}{\mu}\pars{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu - 1/3} \over 1 - x}\,\,\dd x
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu - 2/3} \over 1 - x}\,\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 108}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\ \partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{\mu + {2 \over 3}} - \Psi\pars{\mu + {1 \over 3}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function*.

---

Then,
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x}
={1 \over 108}\bracks{\Psi''\pars{2 \over 3} - \Psi''\pars{1 \over 3}}
\end{align}
With *Euler Reflection Formula*
$\ds{\Psi''\pars{1 - z}
     =\Psi''\pars{z} + 2\pi^{3}\cot\pars{\pi z}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi z}}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^4 + x^2 + 1}\,\dd x}
={1 \over 54}\,\pi^{3}\ \overbrace{\cot\pars{\pi \over 3}}^{\dsc{1 \over \root{3}}}
\ \overbrace{\csc^{2}\pars{\pi \over 3}}^{\dsc{4 \over 3}}
\ = \color{#66f}{\large{2\root{3} \over 243}\,\pi^{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

May be, this will be totally off-topic; if this is the case, please, forgive me.

What I found interesting is that $$I=\int \frac{x \big(\ln(x)\big)^2}{x^4 + x^2 + 1}\text{ d}x$$ has  (found by a CAS) a closed form mainly in terms of polylogarithms.

The next point is that, using the so-found antiderivative, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x \big(\ln(x)\big)^2}{x^4 + x^2 + 1}\text{ d}x=\frac{2 \pi ^3}{81 \sqrt{3}}$$